# Datediff not working on Excel

Tags: dax

I am trying to write a DAX query and it is always returning me an error.

What I want to calculate hours different 2 columns -

So I have --

- `StartTime` 2015-03-02 09:00
- `EndTime` 2015-03-02 18:00

So I want to calculate the hours different between two ---

```
 DATEDIFF([StartTime]; [EndTime];HOUR)
```

but this query is not working !

Do anyone knows where I am making the mistake !

Answer (score 0):

This function works only if you use Excel 2016 or Power Bi. if you want to have the same result on Excel 2013/2010 you can use this workaround:

```
=([end date]-[Start date])*24`
```